# Get desktop bounds without GraphicsDevice.getConfigurations()

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am new to Java and trying to determine how GraphicsDevice.getDefaultConfiguration() differs from what GraphicsDevice.getConfigurations() returns.

Some users are getting a serious slowdown when they start out application. I have found one machine that reproduces the issue which I am thinking is cause by this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6477756

This led me to see if I can avoid using GraphicsDevice.getConfigurations(). I just need to know the bounds of the desktop and I see two ways to do it.  They seem to do the same thing in all my testing but I hope someone knowledgeable can tell me if there will be different behavior in some situations.

Method 1

```
Rectangle result = new Rectangle();
for (GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice : graphicsEnv.getScreenDevices()) {
   for (GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration :  graphicsDevice.getConfigurations()) {
      Rectangle2D.union(result, graphicsConfiguration.getBounds(), result);
   }
}
```

Method 2

```
GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnv =   GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle result = new Rectangle();
for (GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice : graphicsEnv.getScreenDevices()) {
        Rectangle2D.union(result,  graphicsDevice.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds(), result);
}
```

Method 2 is much faster on the machine that reproduces the users slowdown.  Is there any reason not to use it instead?

Comment: I would say the short answer would be no, there is no reason

Comment: Thanks.  From my testing they are working the same.  The person who made the change said that with method 2, if you had a laptop with an extra monitor, and undocked it, method two would still include the extra monitor in the returned Rectangle.  Cannot reproduce this though so maybe it is hardware specific, or a patch has fixed it.